# React Navigation: `useLinkProps` not generating correct link in browser

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I am using react-navigation v6 and expo 49. Bundler for web is webpack.

I need help with react navigation. It is around how links are generated. I have created a linking config which has a config like

```js
[screenNames.itemDetail]: {
  path: "item-detail/:itemId",
  exact: true,
}
```

I am using `useLinkProps` to generate href links on web. Here is that code snippet

```js
const { onPress: onLinkPress, ...linkProps } = useLinkProps({
  to: {
    screen: screenNames.itemDetail,
    params: {
      itemId: item.id,
      origin: "search",
    },
  },
});
```

If I am on same browser tab and click on the link that gets generated. I go to correct link which is `/item-detail/40?origin=search`. However, if I use `⌘+click` or `right click to open in new tab`, the link that I get is `/item-detail?itemId=40&origin=search`. Notice that `itemId` is a param now.

How do I make sure that link that is generated is always `item-detail/40`?

Here is a snack link that reproduces this issue [https://snack.expo.dev/@khageshfoodapp/hello-react-navigation-|-react-navigation](https://snack.expo.dev/@khageshfoodapp/hello-react-navigation-%7C-react-navigation)

I don't want to create the exact link string myself. I know I can always serialize params for query string myself and give react navigation the exact path. By doing this, I loose strict type checking for params and screen names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I needed to pass exact same structure to `useLinkProps` as we have in our navigator. So, if I do below then everything is fine.

```js
useLinkProps({
  to: {
    screen: "main-drawer",
    params: {
      screen: screenNames.itemDetail,
      params: {
        itemId: item.id,
        origin: "search",
      },
    },
});
```